# jQuery not picking "label" elements in a DIV

Tags: jquery

I get this error "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: label"
when trying to access label elements in a DIV.
Is this a bug or i am doing something wrong ?

```
    $('#app_loader :input').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#app_loader: label').css('color','#000000');
```

Comment: Check your spaces. They've got meaning in a CSS selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#app_loader input').attr('disabled', false);
$('#app_loader label').css('color','#000000');
```

Your current code does not take labels or inputs inside the div with id #app_loader. That ":" does not belong there. Although ":input" is correct, I recommend you use the regular css-way because it's faster. If you really require all form elements you can keep the ":" for the input, but for the label it's wrong.

Comment: i'm not sure how it was picking the input tags and not the label tag.. nywayz thanks :)

Comment: yeah, because the label tag is a separate element that is not included by the ":input". The second rule is for selecting all the labels inside #app_loader.

Answer (score 1):

use `$('#app_loader label')`. instead of `$('#app_loader: label')..`
Same goes for the input thing

Comment: How can mine not work and JNDPNT's does, its the exact same code >.< JOKES?

Comment: u had suggested changing the position of :

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input#app_loader').attr('disabled', false);
 $('label#app_loader').css('color','#000000');
```